# NSData initWithContentsOfURL: options: errorPtr: delegate object?

Tags: iphone, delegates, nsurlconnection, download, nsdata

Is there a way to assign some sort of delegate object when

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:... options:... errorPtr:...]
```

is called so that I can monitor percentage complete of a download or is the best way to handle this sort of thing through the use of the asynchronous NSURLConnection stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSData initWithContentsOfUrl` is a synchronized call that is not meant to provide progress info.  You should use `NSURLConnection` asynchronized call instead.

If you want to animate a `UIProgressView`, you should consider using [`ASIHTTTPRequest` library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).  It's a very neat library.